# Sharepoint media webpart not able to see any videos

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, ootb

i am not able to see any video in the media web part after providing the url, things i tried.

1. installed silver light application on the system.

but still it shows **install silverlight** when i configure any of the video url from youtube or anyother streaming sites

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please go to IE Options->Programs->manage add-ons, make sure "Microsoft Silverlight" is enabled, like the below:
[image]

After the above, close all IE tabs, and re-open your site using IE again.